# W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied and E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main for unknow reason

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in java coding. I am getting this error "W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied" when I tried to follow the tutorial video where use Firebase to access the realtime database. The program does not showing the homeactivity after the login is done. And I tried to modified the rules in realtime database from false to true, it come out the other error of "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main PID17903". I tried to solve by searching for few days already but still cannot solve this problem.

Here is the main activity for my program.

```js
package com.example.realtimelocationtracking10;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.realtimelocationtracking10.HomeActivity;
import com.example.realtimelocationtracking10.Model.User;
import com.example.realtimelocationtracking10.Utils.Common;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;


import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference user_information;
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        Paper.init(this);

        //Init firebase
        user_information = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_INFORMATION);

        //Init provider
        providers = (List<AuthUI.IdpConfig>) Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        //Request permission location
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        showSignInOptions();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must accept permission to use app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    }
                }).check();
    }

    private void showSignInOptions() {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),MY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //Ctrl + O

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                //Check if user exists on database
                user_information.orderByKey()
                        .equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) //If user not exists
                                {
                                    if(!dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) //if key uid is not exists
                                    {
                                        Common.loggedUser = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(), firebaseUser.getEmail());
                                        //Add to database
                                        user_information.child(Common.loggedUser.getUid())
                                                .setValue(Common.loggedUser);
                                    }
                                }
                                else //If user is available
                                {
                                    Common.loggedUser = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).getValue(User.class);
                                }

                                //Save UID to storage to update location from background
                                //Paper.book().write(Common.USER_UID_SAVE_KEY, Common.loggedUser.getUid());
                                updateToken(firebaseUser);
                                setupUI();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        //Navigate Home
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void updateToken(final FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.TOKENS);

        //Get Tokens
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                        tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                                .setValue(instanceIdResult.getToken());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my Home Activity code.

```js
package com.example.realtimelocationtracking10;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView =findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        //Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_find_people) {
           startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AllPeopleActivity.class));
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_add_people) {

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    }
```

Here is my content_home code.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingVie..."
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the rules for my realtime database.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true", 
  }
}
```

This is the error in logcat and Stracktrace when I use above rules for the realtime database.

```js
package com.example.realtimelocationtracking10;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView =findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        //Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_find_people) {
           startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AllPeopleActivity.class));
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_add_people) {

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    }
```

Hope can have people can help me to solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The security rules for your database reject all read and write operations, so it makes sense that you get a `Permission denied` response. I recommend [searching for that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+DatabaseError%3A+Permission+denied), and reading the [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) (the video in that link is also really good).

Comment: Your current rules and error message are explained by the links I added. If you get another error after opening up the rules to allow the operation, please post the rules and [*minimal* code for that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have change the code for the rules in the realtime database after doing some researches and the other error, E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main is obtained. So is the rules I edited have problems or the apps coding have problems?

Comment: Please edit yoru question to include the complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: I have edited and the error message is included.